# Open a navigation drawer by image click

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have a Navigation Drawer Activity. I just can open the navigation drawer by clicking the home button in Action Bar.

I want to know if it is possible to open it by clicking a ImageView, that would be in a fragment and how to do that.

thanks.

=====
Edit:

I created my activity by the wizard, so I have the MainActivity, the Placeholder Activity (for content) and NavigationDrawerActivity (for actionBar and Drawer).

In MainActivity's onCreate(), I have:
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

```
                //Cria menu de navegação
                mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            locationmanager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                    getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
                mTitle = getTitle();
                mDrawerLayout= mNavigationDrawerFragment.getmDrawerLayout();

                // Configura menu de navegação
                mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
                        R.id.navigation_drawer,
                        (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
```

In Placeholder fragment I have:

```
 rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.logoInicio);
                imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Log.i("Image click", "Clicked");
                        if (main.mNavigationDrawerFragment!=null){
                            if (!main.mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
                                main.mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(main.mydrawer);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
```

The navigationDrawer fragment is just like the wizard left.

This is my stacktrace:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: workshopee.ct.ufrn.br.ssmonitor, PID: 15902
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at workshopee.ct.ufrn.br.ssmonitor.PlaceholderFragment$2.onClick(PlaceholderFragment.java:144)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4456)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18462)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. On button click use:
`((YourActivityWithDrawer)getActivity()).drawerLayout.openDrawer(your_drawer);`

where:

- `YourActivityWithDrawer` is your `Activity` containing drawer,
- `drawerLayout` is your `DrawerLayout` object
- `your_drawer` is the actual drawer object.

Method is described [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html#openDrawer(android.view.View))

Comment: You can also use `drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT)`, or whatever gravity you used on your drawer's layout.

Comment: Agree but passing named view of specific drawer seems more readable.

Comment: Hi, You need to find main.mydrawer just like you did with mDrawerLayout.
I suppose it's null at the moment. 
Below this line:

`mDrawerLayout= mNavigationDrawerFragment.getmDrawerLayout();`
insert this line:
`mydrawer = mNavigationDrawerFragment.findViewById(R.id.id_of_your_drawer)`

Comment: I got it! But mNavigationDrawerFragment hasn't findViewById method. I'll post my solution.

Comment: @questioner I am still getting the invoke virtual method error on image click in android

Answer (score 0):

I created these two global variables in MainActivity:

```
DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
int fragmentId;
```

MainActivity's onCreate() looks like that:

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

```
                //Cria menu de navegação
                mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                        getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
                mTitle = getTitle();

                fragmentId = R.id.navigation_drawer;
                drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
                // Configura menu de navegação
                mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
                        fragmentId,
                        drawerLayout);
```

And, finally, my Placeholder fragment:

```
rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.logoInicio);
                imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (main.mNavigationDrawerFragment!=null){
                            if (!main.mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
                                main.drawerLayout.openDrawer(getActivity().findViewById(main.fragmentId));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
```